# Move properties from relation to node in Neo4J on large datasets

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to move a property I've set up on a relationship in Neo4J to one of it's member nodes, because I want to index that property, and as of version 2.2.5 which I am using, indexing on relationships is not possible.

However, when I try to move it via Cypher command `MATCH (k)-[l]->(m) SET m.key = l.key`, my request also drops due to a lack of memory. I have no possibility to add additional memory either.

Does any one know of a good way to do this without having to resort to lots of memory when dealing with large (ca. 20M) datasets?

Comment: If it's of any help: My database size is about 9GB, and the RAM of my installation is 12GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to go for an unmanaged extension because you are moving the properties as a one-time problem you can also write e.g. a shell script which  calls the linux curl command and loops in a loop with skip and limit. This has the advantage that you don't need to move the values but can copy them.

```
MATCH (k)-[l]->(m)
WITH l skip 200000 limit 100000
SET m.key = l.key
RETURN COUNT(*) AS nRows
```

Replace 200000 with the value of the loop variable.

Comment: Sounds quite good, but as it seems, I've actually succeeded with the unmanaged extension. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: In the end, I settled for this solution. The WITH statement was what I was actually missing before. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If it's one time operation I highly recommend you to write [Unmanaged Extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

It will be much faster than Cypher.

Here is an example

```
Label startNodeLabel = DynamicLabel.label("StartNode");
Label endNodeLabel = DynamicLabel.label("EndNode");
RelationshipType relationshipType = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("RelationshipType");
String nodeProperty = "nodeProperty";
String relationshipProperty = "relationshipProperty";

try(Transaction tx = database.beginTx()) {
    final ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = database.findNodes(startNodeLabel);

    for (Node startNode : IteratorUtil.asCollection(nodes)) {
        if (startNode.hasRelationship(relationshipType, Direction.OUTGOING)) {
            final Iterable<Relationship> relationships = startNode.getRelationships(relationshipType, Direction.OUTGOING);

            for (Relationship relationship : relationships) {
                final Node endNode = relationship.getOtherNode(startNode);

                if (endNode.hasLabel(endNodeLabel)) {
                    endNode.setProperty(nodeProperty, relationship.getProperty(relationshipProperty));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tx.success();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exactly like I was looking for. I'll try that out.

Comment: Trying to set it up properly, but having some problems on how to write unmanaged extension. The documentation I found from neo4j is not very exhaustive. When trying to adopt your example, I have problems resolving `RelationshipTypes` in ```RelationshipType relationshipType = RelationshipTypes.valueOf("RelationshipType");```. Any hints, where I can get more in depth documentation on that topic?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it running. When it succeeds, I'll accept the answer. In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Well in the end, I still didn't succeed, the extension just stopped working and I was not able to find the problem. But I learned something about writing extensions for Neo4J so still really helpful answer, though I settled with a different solution in the end. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `LIMIT` to limit the query to a specific number of rows, and then repeat the query until no more rows are returned. That will also limit the amount of memory usage.

For example, if you also wanted to remove the `key` property from the relationship at the same time (and you wanted to process 100K rows each time):

[EDITED]

```
MATCH (k)-[l]->(m)
WHERE HAS(l.key)
SET m.key = l.key
REMOVE l.key
WITH l
LIMIT 100000
RETURN COUNT(*) AS nRows;
```

This query will return an `nRows` value of 0 when you are done.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, since with keyword `LIMIT` you seem to only limit the rows for the output, but neo4j seems to still make the query on the whole dataset. In your example, the use of `LIMIT` seems actually quite pointless, because `RETURN COUNT(*) AS nRows` will always return only one row.

I had the same idea myself and tried it, but it gets me the same result

Comment: Tweaked my answer a bit so that the `LIMIT` does actually get applied.

Comment: Thanks, now it's similar to the solution michaeak proposed. Really helpful, thanks. Unfortunately, I can only mark one solution as correct, and he came up with the correct syntax earlier, but I upvoted all answers, since they all have been very helpful